# AccessViolationException unhandled on C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have added a TextBox on my Form, and on the TextChanged event I have written the following code to enable AutoCompleteSource :

```
private void txtNameCostBL_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNameCostBL.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        txtNameCostBL.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new              
        AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        for (int i = 0; i < dtCustomerForSalesBl.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            col.Add(dtCustomerForSalesBl.Rows[i][1].ToString());
        }
        txtNameCostBL.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;
    }
```

It works fine, but sometimes when I'm writting something it raises the AccessViolation shown on the image.

[>> Error Screenshot <<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOQSj.png)

I hope you can give me a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Dear @Thread could you translate your question to english please? This platform is completely English and most programmers program in English. (as your code is also english)

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you asking: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, *it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking*.

Comment: You probably can only update UI from a UI thread (as far as my knowledge of apps go)?

Comment: @JoelHarkes Sorry I thought this platform in French and thanx, this is the translate for the exception : Attempt to read or write protected memory. This often indicates that another memory is damaged.

Answer (score 0):

it's a security level problem may be. try this: 
Go to the Project Property page, and then go into the Security Section.

**"Enable ClickOnce Security Settings" will be seen checked. uncheck it**

reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e599b2e2-3cda-43ad-b15f-a69b4fea1a75/dynamic-filling-of-textbox-autocomplete-not-working?forum=winforms

**edit**

Sorry to say I can't test but, have you seen this part in the link i shared earlier? they considered it as answer

> Hi,
>
> I have been facing the same issue. I inspected and learned that if you
>   have null as a value in suggestions it always crashed without a clue.
>   Just get rid of all null strings from your autocomplete source and it
>   works like magic!
>
> hope that helps,
>
> Digvijay

Comment: i went to the security section and i find "Enable ClickOnce Security Settings" already unchecked

Comment: sorry i went to the link you shared but i didn't see that part, ok i readed the answer and i checked my autocomplete source but it hasn't any null strings.  thanks for answering :)

Comment: dtCustomerForSalesBl.Rows[i][1].ToString() this line, if you could write it like this: dtCustomerForSalesBl.Rows[i][1]?.ToString() see if compiler allows it. I am suspecting the error happens during ToString() phase of this code block

Comment: dtCustomerForSalesBl.Rows[i][1]?.ToString() does not compile, ok i think that i resolve it, the code that i wrote in the textChanged Event of the textbox i cut it and paste it in a click event of a button, because i find it doesn't make a sense to repeat the code execution in any text change, now it's work good, but i don't know what was the problem even now. thanx a lot

Comment: good to know that.. may be in textChanged event you tried to do operation on same memory location. As string is immutable, AccessViolationException  is happening because of that rather then saving the changed string in new memory location. on the other hand, button click event triggers and write in new memory location. that's my guess. if you found any clue what happened here, post it as answer. people will be benefited.. :)

Comment: you convinced me by your explanation, thank you :)  if i find anything else i'll post it